# How to reference to a varialble in ASP.net within SQL WHERE query

Tags: c#, html, mysql, asp.net, .net

This maybe a simple question but how to reference a string variable within a SQL query? I am simply building a test page to output my data but anything I try keeps throwing syntax errors. Below is what I had but not sure how to reference it in ASp.nET.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient" %>
DIM username As string = "Convert.ToString(User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\") + 1))"
<script language="VB" runat="server">

Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim myConnection  As MySqlConnection
    Dim myDataAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myDataSet     As DataSet

    Dim strSQL        As String
    Dim iRecordCount  As Integer

        myConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user id=Directory_Admin; password=IMCisgreat2014; database=imc_directory_tool; pooling=false;")

        strSQL = "SELECT username FROM tbl_staff WHERE username  = "


    myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnection)
    myDataSet = New Dataset()
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tbl_staff")

    MySQLDataGrid.DataSource = myDataSet
    MySQLDataGrid.DataBind()

End Sub

</script>

<html>
<head>
<title>Simple MySQL Database Query</title>
</head>
<body>

<form runat="server">

<asp:DataGrid id="MySQLDataGrid" runat="server" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Updated code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient" %>
<script language="VB" runat="server">
Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim username As String = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
    Dim myConnection  As MySqlConnection
    Dim myDataAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myDataSet     As DataSet
        Dim strSQL As String
    Dim iRecordCount  As Integer

        myConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user id=Directory_Admin; password=IMCisgreat2014; database=imc_directory_tool; pooling=false;")

        strSQL = "SELECT username FROM tbl_staff WHERE username = '" & username & "'"

    myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnection)
    myDataSet = New Dataset()
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tbl_staff")

    MySQLDataGrid.DataSource = myDataSet
    MySQLDataGrid.DataBind()

End Sub

</script>

<html>
<head>
<title>Simple MySQL Database Query</title>
</head>
<body>

<form runat="server">

<asp:DataGrid id="MySQLDataGrid" runat="server" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well it's not hard to see why it's throwing errors. First, move your dim statement inside the script tag, second, remove the double quotes around the Convert.ToString function, third, strSQL should have either a parameter for the name, or add the name to it. I.e. `WHERE username = '" & username & "'"`. Oh, also, you should probably open the MySqlConnection as well, and then close it when your done.

Comment: @EBrown A DataAdapter.Fill method opens the connection if it is closed. After usage, the adapter closes the connection (if it was closed). I agree with the other parts though.

Comment: @Steve Ah, thanks for that. I never use DataAdapters, nor do I use MySQL. Good to know though.

Comment: Yeah major screw up on my part, made the changes and no longer getting errors on my page however my user name variable seems to be returning blank. I tried changing the variable from `DIM username As string = "Convert.ToString(User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\") + 1))"
<script language="VB" runat="server"> ` to `Dim username As String = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")` but still seems to be returning blank. Doing `<%=User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\") + 1)%>` seems to return the proper data. NOt sure where its failing.

Comment: Oh never-mind I got it to work, I think I had a typo in the actual username in the DB. updated with the final code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that resolved my issue:

```
@ Page Language="VB" debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient" %>
<script language="VB" runat="server">
Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim username As String = Convert.ToString(User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\") + 1))
    Dim myConnection  As MySqlConnection
    Dim myDataAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myDataSet     As DataSet
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim iRecordCount  As Integer

        myConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user id=Directory_Admin; password=IMCisgreat2014; database=imc_directory_tool; pooling=false;")

        strSQL = "SELECT username FROM tbl_staff WHERE username = '" & username & "'"

    myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnection)
    myDataSet = New Dataset()
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tbl_staff")

    MySQLDataGrid.DataSource = myDataSet
    MySQLDataGrid.DataBind()

End Sub

</script>

<html>
<head>
<title>Simple MySQL Database Query</title>
</head>
<body>

<form runat="server">

<asp:DataGrid id="MySQLDataGrid" runat="server" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Test your application with the username `' OR ''='`.